# Output ALL results at the end of foreach instead of during each run

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I inherited a script which loops through a set of servers in a server list and then outputs some stuff for each one. It uses StringBuilder to append stuff to a variable and then spits out the results...how do I get the script to store the contents so I can display it at the VERY end with the results of the entire foreach instead of having it print (and then overwrite) on each iteration?

Currently my results look like this:

```
ServerName1
  Text1
```

Next run:

```
ServerName2
 Text 2
```

How do I get it to store the data and then output the following at the end so I can email it?

```
ServerName1
 Text1

ServerName2
 Text2
```

My code:

```
foreach($Machine in $Machines)
    {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock{param($XML1,$XML2,$XML3,$URL)
            [System.Text.StringBuilder]$SB = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
            $X = $SB.AppendLine($env:COMPUTERNAME)
            if (Test-Path <path>)
            {        
                $PolResponse = <somestuff>
                $PolResponse2 = <somestuff>
                Write-Host "[1st] $PolResponse" -ForegroundColor Magenta
                Write-Host "[2nd] $PolResponse2" -ForegroundColor Magenta
                $X = $SB.AppendLine($PolResponse)
                $X = $SB.AppendLine($PolResponse2)
            }
            else
            {
                $PolResponse = "[1st] No Response"
                $PolResponse2 = "[2nd] No Response"
                Write-Host $PolResponse -ForegroundColor Red
                Write-Host $PolResponse2 -ForegroundColor Red
                $X = $SB.AppendLine($PolResponse)
                $X = $SB.AppendLine($PolResponse2)
            }
        } -ArgumentList $XML1, $XML2, $XML3, $URL
    }

    # Sending result email

    <<I want to send the TOTALITY of $SB here>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by moving the StringBuilder variable declaration outside of the for loop (prior to it)
[System.Text.StringBuilder]$SB = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

then FOR LOOP

Comment: Thanks @codemaker. I had to finish up a basic script to notify via email of any issues so when I revisit this to tweak it I'll definitely give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be a good solution for what you're asking for or not, but what you could do is create a txt file and every loop in the foreach loop add the information to a txt file. This is one way to store all of the information and then have all of it together at the end.

```
New-Item -Path "\\Path\to\file.txt" -Itemtype File

Foreach(){
    $Stuff = # Do your stuff here
    Add-Content -Value $stuff -Path "\\Path\to\file.txt"
}

# Email .txt file ?
# You could use Send-MailMessage to do this possibly
```

Hopefully this can be helpful for your goal.

Comment: Thanks @Cory Etmund, I'll keep this on the back burner. I had to finish up a basic script to notify via email of any issues so when I revisit this to tweak it I'll definitely give this a run.